# How can I add text data (timestamp) to a picture using camera

Tags: flutter, image, dart, time, draw

I used image library, but it doesn't support creating background for text

design [image]

Comment: A mention of an *image library*, an image and *help me* is not an acceptable question here. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages (and actually reading them instead of clicking through the links) to learn how the site works before posting your next question here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Stack widget. I think it will help.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Use it like this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    CameraWidget(), // or ImageWidget(),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: TextWidget(),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).